# Can't play game from zip file

Tags: files, games, zip, extract, unzip

Just downloaded the zip file from https://danidev.itch.io/off-the-balls and after extracting it I still can't find any way to play the game. After extracting, I don't see any .exe files either which seems to be what I'm supposed to see. I'm new to linux and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: If it's Linux native software then you definitely SHOULDN'T be looking for .exe as those are Windows executables.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try making the file executable?

```bsh
chmod +x OffTheBalls.*
./OffTheBalls.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

Those instructions assume you're on windows, so I can see how that'd be misleading. Linux doesn't use `.exe` files, instead it has binaries that are marked as executable that you can run. That's probably an oversimplification, but I'm not the most experienced with Linux either, so correct me if I'm wrong.

What you need to do is unzip the zip file, mark the binary as executable, and finally run the binary . You can do this by executing the following commands:

```sh
unzip OffTheBalls.zip
chmod +x ./OffTheBalls.x86
./OffTheBalls.x86
```

> Those steps worked perfectly for me on Arch Linux and should work the same on Ubuntu